# Sending an array from JS to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

```
$("#gallery li.gallery-image-item:not(:first)").each(function() {    
     formData.append('gallery[]', {file: 'file', comment: 'comment', youTube: 'youtube'});
 });
```

I'm sending my data from js to php using formData and a XMLHttpRequest.

The problem is the above dumps as a string:

```
string(15) "[object Object]"
```

When I loop through it:

```
 foreach($input['gallery'] as $galleryImg) {

        var_dump(($galleryImg));

}
```

How can I get access to it as an array? I've tried json.stringify and json decode + json decode, true on the php side.

No luck.

Comment: That's not an array you're trying to send.

Comment: `append()` isn’t a function on arrays. Did you try to send a jQuery object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @minitech said, `append()` is not a function on arrays. If you want to add items to your array, you need to use the `push()` function. Then you need to stringify your array so that it can be posted to your PHP. Something like this should work:

JavaScript:

```
var gallery = [];
$("#gallery li.gallery-image-item:not(:first)").each(function() {    
 gallery.push({file: 'file', comment: 'comment', youTube: 'youtube'});
 });

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "jsonUrl",
            data: {gallery : JSON.stringify(gallery)},
            success : function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

PHP:

```
var_dump(json_decode($galleryImg));
```